# JAva: why isn't anything being written to my txt file?

Tags: java

```
public static void getMembers(WebDriver driver, String outname){

    FileWriter outFile = null;
    try {
        outFile = new FileWriter(new File("myfile.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //continue from 900
    for(int i=1;i<=5070;i++){
        driver.get("/username&page="+i);

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/a"));
        for(WebElement link : links){

            if (link.getText() == ""){                  
            }else{
            try {
                outFile.write(link.getText() + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(link.getText());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

System.out.println(link.getText()); spits out the appropriate strings....however myfile.txt is empty !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not closed `outFile`:

```
outFile.close();
```

Closing the file flushes any buffered output and writes it to the file on disk. Do this after you have finished writing everything to the file.

Comment: also, opening the file, there are weird black boxes in the text file with o inside the blackbox.

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo, Greg told you where to put it in the answer.  When you are done.  You are likely to see partially written results in the file if you do not finish writing to it.  Beyond that, you may need to research encodings and look at what encoding the editor you are opening it with assumes.